# give focus to a cell of 8 th column of in gridview when loading of page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using VS 2005,asp.net,c#.net.
I have a grid view which is in an update panel.
How to give focus to a cell of 8 th column in grid view when loading of page?

Thanks in advance
George.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no focus on a cell. Focus is always a keyboard focus; this is the attribute of a control, not any of its parts. What you need is selection, which is not related to focus.

Also, the result of selection depends on selection style of your DataGridView.
to select a specific cell you can use this code.

```
this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
datagridview1.CurrentCell = datagridview1[8,0];//replace 0 with row index of datagridview
```